# Wordpress Plugin Opening-Hours on custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am learning to build a custom Wordpress Theme from scratch. I would like to display opening times in the footer. I am trying to use [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-opening-hours/) but i can not find any documentation on it! I just want users to add their opening and close times using this and then output the opening/close times in the footer html. Does anyone have any experience using this plugin / know a better way i can achieve this?

**HTML for foot.php**

```
<div class="w-col w-col-6 w-col-stack">
      <h3 class="heading-6">OPENING TIMES</h3>
      <div class="open-times-wrapper">
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">MONDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">USER INPUT GOES HERE!</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">TUESDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">WEDNESDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">THURSDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">FRIDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">SATURDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="unordered-list">
          <li class="open-li">SUNDAY</li>
          <li class="closeinfo open-li">10:30am - 00:00pm</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the plugin description. All the documentation is on their Github: https://github.com/janizde/WP-Opening-Hours

Comment: It's better if you can add complete answer here.

Comment: I still don't understand, i am not very good with namespaces in PHP!